# Why can't I use `MutableState` as a property delegate?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to use an instance of `MutableState` as a property delegate.

Here's what I have:

`val countState = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }`

Here's what I want:

`var count by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }`

However, when I use the `by` keyword, I get the compiler error:

`Type 'TypeVariable(T)' has no method 'getValue(Nothing?, KProperty<*>)' and thus it cannot serve as a delegate`

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

To serve as a delegate, `MutableState` needs a `getValue` function (for reading values), and a `setValue` function (for writing values).

When you access `MutableState` via `mutableStateOf`, you use the import:

`import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf`

However, this import does not include the `getValue` and `setValue` functions for `MutableState` - they are defined as extension functions in a separate file. To access them, an explicit import on that file is required.

This by itself is not usually a problem - if you type:

`countState.getValue(...)`

Android Studio will auto-suggest the required import for you.

It is a problem, however, when you use the `by` keyword - Android Studio will not auto-suggest the import for you. Instead, it will give the `cannot serve as a delegate` error, without any indication of what you need to do.

So the fix is to manually add the imports for the extension functions yourself:

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
```

Hopefully someone on the IDE team can make this more obvious in the future - an auto-suggestion for the import would be ideal!