# What is the proper way to get status bar height in compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Usually when using Accompanist `Modifier.statusBarsHeight()` the height will change depends on the status bar visibility, if it's visible either **24.dp** or more and if it's invisible the height will be **0.dp**. But i want the height won't change to zero regardless of its visibility.

I've been using this for a while:

```
// TODO: use better solution to get a fixed status bar height
val statusBarHeight = with (LocalDensity.current) { LocalWindowInsets.current.statusBars.top.toDp() }
val fixedStatusBarHeight = remember { statusBarHeight }
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current code? Why you need `remember` here? In case status bar changes it would prevent you from getting an updated value

Comment: @PylypDukhov my composable padding would change if i don't use `fixedStatusBarHeight` when i hide the system bars, since the status bar height would be 0.dp

Comment: why do you want its height when status bar is invisible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, there is an ExperimentalLayoutApi that provides [`statusBarsIgnoringVisibility`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#(androidx.compose.foundation.layout.WindowInsets.Companion).statusBarsIgnoringVisibility()).

Example use case:

I have two screens, A and B. Screen A uses `statusBarsIgnoringVisibility` for top padding. In screen B, you can hide the status bar (e.g., full screen photo). When going from screen B to screen A, I want the top padding in screen A to already equal the full height of the status bar while the status bar comes back into view. Without `statusBarsIgnoringVisibility`, this transition doesn't look very good.

Answer (score 34):

The problem is getting complicated you should use it like this

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .statusBarsPadding().navigationBarsPadding()
            ) {

            }

            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .statusBarsPadding().systemBarsPadding()
            ) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly for me! Correct answer!

Comment: but it doesn't give the height as value (in dp for example), to use with `GoogleMap(contentPadding = PaddingValues()` for example, so your answer works only for specific cases, it's not universal

Comment: Depending on the case you will need the exact exact height of the status bar and navigation bar. But I haven't seen a case where it has to be resolved that way. I've tried getting their sizes and that would be costly to the system's memory. If you try to do it in the compose functions, the performance of the app will drop

Answer (score 4):

So i ended up making a workaround alongside with a modifier extension for easier use.

First, make a data class to hold the fixed inset values.

```
data class FixedInsets(
    val statusBarHeight: Dp = 0.dp,
    val navigationBarsPadding: PaddingValues = PaddingValues(),
)
```

Second, create the extension and a composition local provider.

```
val LocalFixedInsets = compositionLocalOf<FixedInsets> { error("no FixedInsets provided!") }

@Composable
fun Modifier.fixedStatusBarsPadding(): Modifier {
    return this.padding(top = LocalFixedInsets.current.statusBarHeight)
}

@Composable
fun Modifier.fixedNavigationBarsPadding(): Modifier {
    return this.padding(paddingValues = LocalFixedInsets.current.navigationBarsPadding)
}
```

Finally, provide the fixed inset values at the very root of your composable function.

```kt
val systemBarsPadding = WindowInsets.systemBars.asPaddingValues()
val fixedInsets = remember {
    FixedInsets(
        statusBarHeight = systemBarsPadding.calculateTopPadding(),
        navigationBarsPadding = PaddingValues(
            bottom = systemBarsPadding.calculateBottomPadding(),
            start = systemBarsPadding.calculateStartPadding(LayoutDirection.Ltr),
            end = systemBarsPadding.calculateEndPadding(LayoutDirection.Ltr),
        ),
    )
}

CompositionLocalProvider(
    values = arrayOf(
        LocalFixedInsets provides fixedInsets,
    ),
) {
    MainScreen()
}
```

Navigation bar padding example:

```
Text(
    text = "Hello i'm a text with navigation bar padding",
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(color = Color.Red)
        .fixedNavigationBarsPadding(),
)
```

Or you can access the sizes in `Dp` directly from the local composition by using `calculateXPadding()`:

```
val fixedInsets = LocalFixedInsets.current

Text(
    text = "The navigation bar's height is: ${fixedInsets.navigationBarsPadding.calculateBottomPadding()}",
)
```

Comment: I used your approach for getting soft navigatoin bar height...but it always gives me zero values... https://i.imgur.com/n2tAHNx.png

Comment: this solution is 
not working

Answer (score 2):

You can use `WindowInsets.statusBars.getTop(this)`

For example (map takes all screen - behind status and navigation bar):

```
GoogleMap(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState,
    properties = MapProperties(isMyLocationEnabled = true),
    contentPadding = with(LocalDensity.current) {
        PaddingValues(
            top = WindowInsets.statusBars.getTop(this).toDp(),
            bottom = WindowInsets.navigationBars.getBottom(this).toDp()
        )
    }
) {
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For [`TopAppBar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#TopAppBar(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.WindowInsets,androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBarColors,androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBarScrollBehavior)), the following code works for getting its height:

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.*

...
...

@Composable
fun TopAppBarComposable(){
    var topAppBarHeight by remember {mutableStateOf(0.dp)}
    val localDensity = LocalDensity.current
    TopAppBar(
        modifier = Modifier
               .onGloballyPositioned { layoutCoordinates ->
                    with(localDensity){
                        topAppBarHeight = layoutCoordinates.size.height.toDp()
                    }
               }
    )
```

Comment: in the topAppBarHeight var, when assigning a value, this happen:
> Type 'MutableState<Dp>' has no method 'setValue(Nothing?, KProperty<*>, Dp)' and thus it cannot serve as a delegate for var (read-write property)

Comment: @MarlonLópez Add `import androidx.compose.runtime.*` manually and then try, if Android Studio doesn't recommend this import automatically. For more details you can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67360039/14004940).

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I set it, I get the height of the status bar from Resources

```
fun getStatusBarHeight(): Int {
    val resources = Resources.getSystem()
    val resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android")
    return resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId)
}

@Composable
fun Modifier.paddingBarHeight() = composed {
    padding(top = remember { getStatusBarHeight() })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the statusbarheight or inset for compose you need to do the following.

Step 1:
include the following in the oncreate of you activity

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
}
```

Step 2:
After you included the setDecorFitsSystemWindows into your activity onCreate you need to add the following to the manifest of your activity.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Step 3:
To add the statusbar padding to your composable you can use the following modifier:

```
modifier = modifier.windowInsetsPadding(WindowInsets.safeDrawing)
```

Or if you want to use any other insetPaddings you can use the WindowInsets class. I've read a lot a issues on stackoverflow of people getting 0.0dp returned as there padding inset. That's because you forgot the setup part in step 1 and 2.

Hope this helps :)