Toolbar overlapping on the text and whenever I create a function outside the MainActivity Class it doesn't gets launched
Whenever I execute the text, the text overlapping over the toolbar and whenever I create a function outside the MainActivity Class it doesn't gets launched. Also when I try to make a separate function and call it from main function it doesn't show the result
Here, what I am doing

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73710932/14162959
